# Self-Join with Natural Join

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between

```
select * from degreeprogram  NATURAL JOIN degreeprogram ;
```

and

```
select * from degreeprogram d1 NATURAL JOIN degreeprogram d2;
```

in oracle?
I expected that they return the same result set, however, they do not. The second query does what I expect: it joins the two relations using the same named attributes and so it returns the same tuples as stored in degreeprogram. However, the first query is confusing for me: here, each tuple occurs several times in the result set-> what join condition is used here?

Thank you

Comment: Presumably this is Oracle 11g or earlier, as in 12.2 it fails with `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`. However using `select count(*)` allows it to proceed, giving a Cartesian product of non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NATURAL JOIN` means join the two tables based on all columns having the same name in both tables.

I imagine that for each column in your table, Oracle is internally writing a condition like:

```
degreeprogram.column1 = degreeprogram.column1
```

(which you would not be able to write yourself due to `ORA-00918` column ambiguously defined error)

And then, I imagine, Oracle is optimizing that away to just

```
degreeprogram.column1 is not null
```

So, you're not exactly getting a `CROSS JOIN` of your table with itself -- only a `CROSS JOIN` of those rows having no null columns.

UPDATE: Since this was the selected answer, I will just add from Thorsten Kettner's answer that this behavior is probably a bug on Oracle's part.  In 18c, Oracle behaves properly and returns an `ORA-00918` error when you try to `NATURAL JOIN` a table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those two statements is that the second explicitly defines a self join on the table, where the first statement, the optimizer is trying to figure out what you really want. On my database, the first statement performs a cartesian merge join and is not optimized at all, and the second statement has a better explain plan, using a single full table access with index scanning.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the optimiser, it is all about parsing.

Answer (score 0):

A so-called `natural join` instructs the database to

1. Find all column names common to both tables (in this case, `degreeprogram` and `degreeprogram`, which of course have the same columns.)
2. Generate a join condition for each pair of matching column names, in the form `table1.column1 = table2.column1` (in this case, there will be one for every column in `degreeprogram`.)

Therefore a query like this

```
select count(*) from demo natural join demo;
```

will be transformed into

```
select count(*) from demo, demo where demo.x = demo.x;
```

I checked this by creating a table with one column and two rows:

```
create table demo (x integer);

insert into demo values (1);
insert into demo values (2);
commit;
```

and then [tracing the session](http://structureddata.org/2011/08/18/creating-optimizer-trace-files/):

```
SQL> alter session set tracefile_identifier='demo_trace';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set events 'trace [SQL_Compiler.*]';

Session altered.

SQL> select /* nj test */ count(*) from demo natural join demo;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

1 row selected.

SQL> alter session set events 'trace [SQL_Compiler.*] off';

Session altered.
```

Then in twelve_ora_6196_demo_trace.trc I found this line:

```
Final query after transformations:******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******
SELECT COUNT(*) "COUNT(*)" FROM "WILLIAM"."DEMO" "DEMO","WILLIAM"."DEMO" "DEMO" WHERE "DEMO"."X"="DEMO"."X"
```

and a few lines later:

```
try to generate single-table filter predicates from ORs for query block SEL$58A6D7F6 (#0)
finally: "DEMO"."X" IS NOT NULL
```

(This is merely an optimisation on top of the generated query above, as column `X` is nullable but the join allows the optimiser to infer that only non-null values are required. It doesn't replace the joins.)

Hence the execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Id  | Operation              | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Time      |
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 0   | SELECT STATEMENT       |         |       |       |     7 |           |
| 1   |  SORT AGGREGATE        |         |     1 |    13 |       |           |
| 2   |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN |         |     4 |    52 |     7 |  00:00:01 |
| 3   |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | DEMO    |     2 |    26 |     3 |  00:00:01 |
| 4   |    BUFFER SORT         |         |     2 |       |     4 |  00:00:01 |
| 5   |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | DEMO    |     2 |       |     2 |  00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
Query Block Name / Object Alias(identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------------------------
 1 - SEL$58A6D7F6         
 3 - SEL$58A6D7F6         / DEMO_0001@SEL$1
 5 - SEL$58A6D7F6         / DEMO_0002@SEL$1
------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information:
----------------------
3 - filter("DEMO"."X" IS NOT NULL)
```

Alternatively, let's see what `dbms_utility.expand_sql_text` does with it. I'm not quite sure what to make of this given the trace file above, but it shows a similar expansion taking place:

```
SQL> var result varchar2(1000)
SQL> exec dbms_utility.expand_sql_text('select count(*) from demo natural join demo', :result)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT COUNT(*) "COUNT(*)" FROM  (SELECT "A2"."X" "X" FROM "WILLIAM"."DEMO" "A3","WILLIAM"."DEMO" "A2" WHERE "A2"."X"="A2"."X") "A1"
```

**Lesson:** `NATURAL JOIN` is evil. Everybody knows this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this a bug. This query:

```
select * from degreeprogram d1 NATURAL JOIN degreeprogram d2;
```

translates to

```
select col1, col2, ... -- all columns
from degreeprogram d1
join degreeprogram d2 using (col1, col2, ...)
```

and gives you all rows from the table where all columns are not null (because `using(col)` never matches nulls).

This query, however:

```
select * from degreeprogram NATURAL JOIN degreeprogram;
```

is invalid according to standard SQL, because every table must have a unique name or alias in a query. Oracle lets this pass, but doing so it should do something still to keep the table instances apart (e.g. create internally an alias for them). It obviously doesn't and multiplies the result with the number of rows in the table. A bug.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP has simplified the query because the `select *` fails for me in 12.2. I used `select count(*)` for testing.

Comment: @William Robertson: With `select *` the queries work for me as described by the OP. With `select count(*)` I get the described counts. I'm using Oracle 11.2. So maybe the bug has been fixed in Oracle 12c.

Comment: That's interesting. The error in 12.2 is `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` which I think is what you expected.